# Looping through mappings in Python

Tags: python

I'm wanting to create a Mapping like so:

```
assets = {'first': ['type1','type2','type3'], 'second': ['type1','type2']}
```

Just a simple Mapping *(associative array)*. I'm not sure if the syntax above is correct *(new to python)*, but that is the idea I'm going for.

Now, I want to be able to loop through the mapping:

```
for key, value in assets:
```

But that returns an error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for key, value in assets.items():
```

The default iterator for a `dict` is just the key values. The use of `items()` produces a sequence of (key, value) tuples.

Comment: Note that, assuming you're using Python 2, `assets.iteritems()` does the same thing and is more efficient.